# iptables logging to diferent file via syslog-ng

Tags: syslog-ng

I have the following configuration in my iptables and syslog files:

IPTABLES

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 222 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -j DROP

-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
```

SYSLOG-NG

```
destination d_iptables { file("/var/log/iptables/iptables.log"); };

filter f_iptables { facility(kern) and match("IN=" value("MESSAGE")) and match("OUT=" value("MESSAGE")); };

filter f_messages { level(info,notice,warn) and
                    not facility(auth,authpriv,cron,daemon,mail,news) and not 
filter(f_iptables); };

log { source(s_src); filter(f_iptables); destination(d_iptables); };`
```

I restart syslog-ng and the log is not written.

Comment: What is the value of `s_src` and why don't you match on "iptables denied:" instead?

Comment: ok I changed my match to look like this

Comment: filter f_iptables { level(debug) and match("IN=" value("iptables denied")) and match("OUT=" value("iptables denied")); };

Comment: source s_src { unix-dgram("/dev/log"); internal();
             file("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syslog-ng config appears fine to me but your iptables config isn't.  The `-j LOG` line appears after a line that DROPs everything, hence it will never be reached.

You should move the LOG line to directly before whatever event you want to log.  If you want to log everything, put it first.  If you want to log everything that isn't ACCEPTed, put it after all the ACCEPTs.

Comment: I moved the logging up as suggested

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:222 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql 
DROP       all  --  static-ip-85-25-146-0.inaddr.ip-pool.com/24  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Comment: and mofified the filter as follows hoping to capture all logging

                                                                                    filter f_iptables { level(debug); };

and still get no output to my iptables.log

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after a lot of pain I finally got it working, here is the final config, I hope it helps someone.

iptables

```
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :LOGNDROP - [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [63:18352]
    -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
    -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 222 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 85.25.146.0/24 -j DROP 
    -A INPUT -j DROP
```

syslog.confg

```
destination d_iptables { file("/var/log/iptables.log"); };
filter f_iptables { match("iptables denied" value("MESSAGE")); };
filter f_debug { level(debug) and not facility(auth, authpriv, news, mail) and not filter(f_iptables); };
#       not facility(auth,authpriv,cron,daemon,mail,news) and not filter(f_iptables); };
filter f_kern { facility(kern) and not filter(f_iptables); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_iptables); destination(d_iptables); };
```

Comment: Great, if this is the correct solution to your question, please mark it as "accepted" when you are able.